# Required directive controller is not present on the current DOM element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I was wondering what actually "required directive controller is not present on the current DOM element" means
here is the link of error:https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=contenteditable

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `ngModel` directive for your custom directive.

Try something like this:

```
app.directive('contenteditable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope) {

          // do something
        }
    };
});
```

and in your HTML file add `ng-model`

```
<contenteditable ng-model="name"></contenteditable>
```

Comment: i have table can you tell me where exactly should i put <contenteditable ng-model="name"></contenteditable>

Comment: i don't understand the question. where do u need this. if its inside table as raw or column just put it inside tr tag or td tag

Answer (score 1):

From the angular.js documentation on directives

When a directive uses require, $compile will throw an error unless the specified controller is found. The ^ prefix means that this directive searches for the controller on its parents (without the ^ prefix, the directive would look for the controller on just its own element).